# Same lines are getting printed

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to make my own document viewer like Google docs. I'm almost done just facing one issue and that issue is same lines are getting printed thrice. I don't know how to correct it.
Below is the code that I have tried to print the text for document viewer
Google docs for viewing document
[image: Google document viewer]

My document viewer
[image: My document viewer]
Can someone help plz?

```
private void textViews(XWPFParagraph paragraph,List<IRunElement> runElements) {
    String paragraphText = paragraph.getParagraphText();

    int size;
    UnderlinePatterns u;
    Boolean b;
    String ff;

    for (IRunElement runElement : runElements) {
        if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
            XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun) runElement;
            System.out.println("runClassName " + run.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("run " + run);


            para.append(run);
            paras.add(para);

            Log.i("font family", run.getFontFamily());
            Log.i("font class", run.getFontName());

            size = run.getFontSize();
            u = run.getUnderline();
            b = run.isBold();
            ff = run.getFontFamily();


                if (paragraphText.length() > 1) {

                    addTextViews(paragraphText, size, b, u, ff);

                }


        }
    }

}

public  void addElements(XWPFPictureData pictureData,long w,long h){


    ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(w/2800),(int)(h/2800)));
    image.setMaxHeight((int)h/2800);
    image.setMaxWidth((int)w/2800);


    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureData.getData());

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mainUI.addView(image);


    // Adds the view to the layout
    LinearLayout imageLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, image.getId());
    imageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    mainUI.addView(imageLayout);




}
```

Console output for textViews function.

I/System.out: TRAVERSE BODY ELEMENTS

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@a4e07b4

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run Flutter Work

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARAINDICES2

```
TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun
```

I/System.out: run Flutter Work

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@a23ea4d

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run First

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

```
run day ,
```

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run  Second day and Third day –

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARAINDICES7

```
TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

run First
```

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run day ,

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

```
run  Second day and Third day –
```

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@73c6902

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

```
run Watched out the flutter tutorials on the YouTube channel – the net 

ninja
```

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARAINDICES12

```
TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun
```

I/System.out: run Watched out the flutter tutorials on the YouTube channel

– the net ninja

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@6438213

```
runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun
```

I/System.out: run In next few days made different apps like –

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARAINDICES15

```
TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun
```

I/System.out: run In next few days made different apps like –

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@a125c50

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run 1 Quotes app – A basic app which displays different

quotes along with their authors

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARAINDICES18

```
TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run 1 Quotes app – A basic app which displays different 

quotes along with their authors 

I/font family: Times New Roman



I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@7d1de49

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run Learnt about 

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run listview

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run  in flutter 

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman


I/System.out: PARAINDICES23

TRAVERSE RUN ELEMENTS

runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run Learnt about 


I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run listview

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: runClassName org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun

I/System.out: run  in flutter 

I/font family: Times New Roman

I/font class: Times New Roman

I/System.out: PARA org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@b8c134e
```

Comment: can you please share console output for `textViews` method, and also, do a print for `paragraphText`?

Comment: You are calling `addTextViews` using the whole `paragraphText` for each text run the paragraph contains. If it contains only one text run, then `addTextViews` gets called once. But if it contains multiple text runs, it gets called multiple times always using the the whole `paragraphText`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I know what's the issue and when I call addTextViews() with run.toString() it prints one word on a single line that's why I used paragraphText. If I call addTextViews() outside for loop I can't get styling like boldness, font family and underlined text. Hence called it inside for loop but then same line is getting printed thrice.